# Get User-Agent using Android API

Tags: android

Kindly provide me the **Android code to get the User-Agent from the Android mobile device** like in J2me where we can get System information about the mobile device using the J2me API.

Also , is there any list of Rdf or useragent string/ xml for the different Android devices available in the market.

Comment: 'kindly provide me' probably isn't going to work - a little more effort is going to be required (send teh codez is bad form)

Comment: I do my homework before posting questions in forums, dont ask questions out of curiosity or guesses.                                                            getProperty("os.name", "os.name", SYSinfoBuffer);
getProperty("os.version", "os.version", SYSinfoBuffer);
SYSinfoBuffer);                                                     SYSinfoBuffer is a StringBuffer in the code . I am unable to get the UserAgent information about the Android mobile device which I am able to do for Blackberry , so posted the question if anyone has already was able to retrieve similar information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#getUserAgentString()

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure you are getting the correct string or you want to check what a browser's user agent string is that works try this site. http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/

Also the user-agent string is modifiable but doing so doesn't change the browser itself. (Learned that the hard way :)

Joshua.

Answer (score 0):

The `User-Agent` header is private to the Browser application. Also note that different browsers (there are quite a few on the market) will use different `User-Agent` strings. Also, I don't know of any list of Android `User-Agent` strings.

If you're just looking to test whether someone is using Android to browse your website, just check for "android" in the `User-Agent` string.